# How do I correlate user between channels?

Tags: botframework

From what I see, Bot Framework is providing an abstraction over users in different channels by providing a `ChannelAccount` class that has `ChannelId`/`Address` pair to identify user via its account and `Id` property, which is... okay, here's the question.

I *suppose* that the idea behind `Id` is to provide a unique and persistent identifier that can be used to cross-correlate users between account (i.e., I can say that Slack user `@alpha` is also email user `alpha@company.con`). This idea is supported by the fact that `ChannelAccount` for my bot always has same `Id` regardless of the channel (and `Address` is different between channels, obviously).

*If* this is right, and I hope it is, is there any way to provide BotConnector with the correlation information? I.e., I want BotConnector to give me `ChannelId`/`Address`, and I'd give back user `Id` which I'd the get back in incoming message.

The purpose of this is quite simple: I want the code inside my bot to use the `Id` as already correlated identifier so that I can log it, build logic from it and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BotFramework does not yet support linking of accounts.  In the interim, take a look at this post for one way you might implement a solution:

[Why isn't BotUserData persisting and retrievable in my Bot Framework bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996859/why-isnt-botuserdata-persisting-and-retrievable-in-my-bot-framework-bot/37997399#37997399)

Comment: I thought about this way of implementing it, but it means that I'll have to use my own identifiers in the system... What'll happen if I simply replace the `ChannelAccount.Id` in incoming message with my own identifier? Will it break something in Bot Framework?

Comment: The ChannelAccount.Id is used by most channels to correctly route the message in the Channel, so changing it will break them.  Support for a universal ID is on the roadmap.  In the interim you'll have to use your own id and a lookup table.  You might also be able to pass it in ChannelData, but you'd have to test.