# Why isn't BotUserData persisting and retrievable in my Bot Framework bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am using dummy messages with user ids to set BotUserData for a particular user, so that the bot can access it elsewhere via the same method.

Example:

```
        message.From.Id = someUserId;            
        message.SetBotUserData("someObject", someObject);
```

Later,
when another user is interacting with the bot, I execute

```
        message.From.Id = someUserId
        someObject = message.GetBotUserData<objectType>("someObject")
```

But someObject is returned as NULL

Note that these two snippets are being executed on different channels, conversations

Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to get the data out for a different user? That's not going to work.

Comment: Is there any other way, then, that I can pass data around between users? (Without them being in the same conversation)

Comment: @stuartd I should clarify - I'm trying to get two users on different channels to talk to each other using the bot as an intermediary. So I'm essentially passing their Channel Accounts using the above method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userId is different on each channel (i.e. Skype / Slack use a different namespace).   BotFramework currently does not provide a means to link accounts between channels.  You could create a user interface that allows users link accounts (for example by generating a token in one channel and having the user type it into another).

```
<SLACK-USER> Get Link code
<SLACK-BOT> Link Code: FSE1-SDF2

<SKYPE-USER> Link account FSE1-SDF2
<SKYPE-BOT>  User linked
```

You'd then want to create your own data store that you can access with the token you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd thought of a similar solution.

Comment: My question was meant to solve the larger problem presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899111/connecting-a-ms-bot-framework-user-to-someone-on-skype?rq=1
Could you perhaps have a look at how one would approach it?